# How to connect from a host to an external dnsmasq running on a VM?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I have a dnsmasq running in a VM image. From the host (where VM is running), I would like to connect to it for name resolution.

How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: What VM software? You need to give details

Comment: Sorry. This is my setup:

Host (Fedora30) -> VMWare15.5 (CentOS7) -> libvirt -> OCP.

There is a dnsmasq configured on VMWare15.5 to resolve the domain names running on OCP.

I would like my Host to have the ability to perform the same name resolution too.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

You can test that `dnsmasq` in the VM is reachable from the host by using `host`, `dig` etc. on the host to do a DNS lookup:

```
host www.google.com 1.2.3.4
```

where `1.2.3.4` is the IP address of the VM. If you don't get an answer, fix the IP setup.

To make the host use the VM as DNS resolver, you ultimately have to put an entry into `/etc/resolv.conf` on the host. However, there's lots of automation that also wants to change this file, so you'll either have to disable this automation, or configure this automation instead. What automation this is depends on your system.